# No change after realloc-call

Tags: c, memory-management, realloc

```
TRANSITION *transitions = malloc(sizeof(TRANSITION));
STATE *destination = malloc(sizeof(STATE));
transitions->destination = (struct STATE *) destination;
int new_size = sizeof(*transitions) + sizeof(TRANSITION);
printf("%d  ", new_size);
transitions = realloc(transitions, new_size);
```

new_size is 32 because sizeof(*transitions) ist 16 and sizeof(TRANSITION) ist 16. Now I want to have transitions have memory of 32 size.

The problem is that if I do:

```
printf("%d  ", sizeof(*transitions));
```

The size of transitions is still 16. Why is it not 32?

Comment: `*transitions` is a top element.

Comment: The size of a struct is fixed at compile-time.  `sizeof(*transitions)` means exactly the same as `sizeof(TRANSITION)`

Comment: As always, you should post the definitions of all types used in your code fragment.  The cast in `transitions->destination = (struct STATE *)destination;` might be unnecessary.

Comment: Why sizeof(*transitions) should be 32?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `sizeof` operator is evaluated at compile time.  Its value is the size of the type of the operand.  You cannot use `sizeof` to retrieve the actual size allocated by `malloc`, `calloc` or `realloc`.  Some `malloc` implementations have  a function to do that, but it is non standard.

If you allocate memory in blocks to store multiple objects or arrays, you must keep track of the allocated space yourself, in separate variables or in structure members.

Note that `printf` format `%d` is or `int` values.  `sizeof` evaluates to a `size_t` value, which is unsigned and might have a different size.  The standard format to convert a `size_t` is `%zu`:

```
printf("%zu  ", sizeof(*transitions));
```

If your C library does not support C99 format specifiers, you would use a cast:

```
printf("%lu  ", (unsigned long)sizeof(*transitions));
```

Comment: Some `sizeof` expressions are evaluated at runtime (not this one though)

Comment: @M.M: some `sizeof` expressions are indeed evaluated at runtime: `sizeof(char[random()])` does make a call to the `random()` function, but `sizeof` applied to an object, as opposed to a type, evaluates to a value that is either a compiler time constant or that was computed as part of the object instantiation (for VLAs).  This does not seem to be the case here, but the type definitions are missing.